# How to match expressions with a repeating pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

The expression I want to match obey a simple pattern that repeats it self a number of times.

```
f[a]@f[b]@f[c]@...@f[X]
```

How would you match all expressions of this form?

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5958128/618728

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### New method

```
SetAttributes[test, HoldAll]
test[f[_] | f[_]@_?test] = True;
test[_] = False;

f[a]@f[b]@f[c] // test
```

> True

This method's advantages are elucidated here:

- [How to define a recursive pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85683/121#86899)

---

#### Old methods for reference

If subexpression evaluation is not a concern:

```
test = MatchQ[#, f[_] | f[_]@_?#0] &;

f[a]@f[b]@f[c] // test
```

> True

To address Leonid's critique that this has evaluation leaks one might instead write:

```
p1 = HoldPattern @ f[_];
test = Function[, MatchQ[Unevaluated@#, p1 | p1@_?#0], HoldFirst];
```

Now it works here too:

```
f[b] = "FAIL!";

f[a]@f[b]@f[c] // test
```

> True

Comment: Well, I guess it works:). +1, I wanted to write something like this but you were first here. We should assume however that the expression won't evaluate, since your test function contains evaluation leaks.

Answer (score 6):

@Mr.Wizard already picked the sweetest answer, but here is my version:

```
Function[Null,
    Switch[Unevaluated@#, 
       HoldPattern[f[_]], True, 
       HoldPattern[f[_][_]], #0 @@ Unevaluated[#], 
       _, False],
    HoldAll]
```

which is basically the same idea, but may be easier (or harder) to comprehend than his solution, depending on how you think. The pattern-matching is done as

```
MatchQ[f[a]@ f[b]@f[c],
  _?(Function[Null, 
        Switch[Unevaluated@#, 
            HoldPattern[f[_]], True, 
            HoldPattern[f[_][_]], #0 @@ Unevaluated[#], 
            _, False], 
        HoldAll])]

(* True *)
```

Note that, if evaluation is not an issue, the above code can be simplified:

```
MatchQ[f[a]@f[b]@f[c], _?(Switch[#, f[_], True, f[_][_], #0 @@ #, _, False] &)]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I fixed that one while you were busy typing the comment. But there is another one - I need `HoldPattern` too.

Comment: Leonid, I added a new method to my answer that I think is cleaner; please tell me if it works or if I'm fooling myself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I like your new method, and I don't see any obvious problem with it.

Comment: btw Leonid, I remember bugging you a while ago re: converting an answer of yours to a blogpost (was it a java related one? I don't remember...). Would you happen to have some time to finish it so that we can push one out? If not, no worries :)

Comment: @R.M I do keep that in mind. Alas, this week is out of the question, I have tons of stuff to do. And so was the last one. I only get short breaks enough to answer questions such as this, but not enough for a blog post. This should be different in a week or something, then I'll try to finish and post it. It won't be Java-related though, I was thinking about the Bessel functions. B.t.w., a few days ago I have finally got a chance to reproduce the bug in the Java reloader that you and a few other folks reported. I fixed it and will soon update the code in my answer where I posted the reloader.

Answer (score 6):

Leonid and Mr.Wizard have given you good answers. Here's a highly unconventional solution that works when `f` has no `*Values` (i.e., it is undefined):

```
test[expr_, patt_] := NestWhile[First, expr, MatchQ[Head[#], patt] &] ~MatchQ~ patt
```

Some examples:

```
test[f[a]@f[b]@f[c], f[_]]
(* True *)

test[f[a]@g[b]@f[c], f[_]]
(* False *)

test[f[a]@f[b]@f[c, d], f[_]]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Unconventional indeed. I like the idea, +1.

Comment: I'm assuming then that if `f` were in a `Block` then this would work?

Comment: @rcollyer `Block` might not be enough, if some other symbols involved in the expression have `UpValues` against `f`.

Answer (score 4):

We can match expressions of the desired form thus:

```
$expr = f[a]@f[b]@f[c]@f[d];

MatchQ[$expr //. f[_]@r_ :> r, _f]

(* True *)

$expr2 = f[a]@f[b]@g[f[c]@f[z]]@f[d];

MatchQ[$expr2 //. f[_]@r_ :> r, _f]

(* False *)
```

This assumes that the transformation rule `f[_]@r_ :> r` does not change an inert expression into one that evaluates.  Given that "hold" attributes cannot be given to compound heads, this is a pretty safe bet.  However, the astute reader will note that the use of `ReplaceRepeated` will operate on subexpressions, not just the surface structure (e.g. `f[c]@f[z]` in `$expr2`).  This opens up more theoretical possibilities for unexpected evaluation.  And it also means that our CPU will heat up more than strictly necessary.  I offer this more complex variant for the ecologically sensitive:

```
MatchQ[$expr //. {x : _f :> x, Except[f[_]@_] -> Null, _@r_ :> r}, _f]

(* True *)
```

This variation ensures that each iteration operates only upon the surface structure of the expression.  And should some <strike>perverse</strike> clever situation arise where evaluation manages to leak from this set-up, we can elaborate even further by sprinkling `Hold` liberally throughout:

```
MatchQ[
  Hold@# &@ $expr //.
    { x : Hold[_f] :> x
    , Except[Hold[f[_]@_]] -> Null
    , Hold[_@r_] :> Hold[r]
    }
  , Hold[_f]
  ]

(* True *)
```

Comment: I initially wasn't going to vote for this answer because I rejected a `//.` method myself (for the reasons you describe) while formulating mine, but your detailed analysis is surely of interest. +1

Comment: All the same people gathered around this question as the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958128/arbitrarily-deep-nested-pattern-matching). If someone would need to gather us for something, it is not hard to come up with a bait question like this. +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the +1.  I thought twice about writing this response for those reasons.  But I finally decided that `//.` was a legitimate strategy -- even without all of the elaborations as I suspect that neither extra replacements nor evaluation leakage are likely to cause problems in practice.  I suppose it depends whether the requirement arises in library code or in a specific application with inputs of known form.  I'd say I'm fond of [YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt), but I guess this post testifies against me :)

Comment: @Leonid True.  We're missing Sasha however.  He still visits but [doesn't post much](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38/sasha?tab=activity&sort=posts) these days; [too busy with mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11069/sasha) I suppose.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes...Sasha betrayed us for maths.