# Getting the "root" Head

Tags: functions, core-language, head

I have a dynamic list of function names, like `{f1, f2, f3, ...}`, and they will enter in computation in various forms `f1[_][_,_,_], f2[_,_], ...`, etc.

I am hoping for a function to **automatically extract their root function names** `f1, f2, ...`; so far I am brute-force checking if `Head[exp]` or `Nest[Head, exp, 2]`, ... but clearly it's ugly.

Comment: Heads are expressions. There's nothing distinguished about a "function" head.

Comment: Related: [(11045)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11045/121)

Comment: What prevents you of using `f[1][_][_,_,_]` instead of `f1[_][_,_,_]`, etc. ?

Comment: @yarchik In the actual code stuffs are not named with f, but other random characters chosen by users. Here I simplify the problem with `f#`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With a few functions to try, defined in `differentfunctions`, try this `headF`:

```
differentfunctions = {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]};
headF = FixedPointList[Head, #][[-3]] &;

headF /@ differentfunctions

(* Out: {f1, f2, f3} *)
```

It relies on the fact that, at some point, repeated application of `Head` will return `Symbol`, and head of `Symbol` is also `Symbol`, so repeated application gets to a fixed point. You then extract the last head before `Symbol` was returned, which is the third-from-last element returned by `FixedPointList` (the last two always being the same, and equal to the fixed point value).

Comment: Wonderful, I was unaware of `FixedPointList` function.

Answer (score 12):

You may use [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html).

With

```
differentfunctions = {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]};
```

Then

```
ReplaceRepeated[h_[___] :> h] /@ differentfunctions
```

> ```
> {f1, f2, f3}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me (version 11) this generates error `ReplaceRepeated::argr: ReplaceRepeated called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.`

Comment: @მ As mentioned in the document, `ReplaceRepeated` is updated in _v11.3_.

Answer (score 12):

There *is* a built-in function `` BoxForm`UltimateHead `` that extracts the head wrapped with `HoldComplete`. So wrapping the output from this function with `ReleaseHold` gives the desired result:

```
topHead = ReleaseHold @* BoxForm`UltimateHead;

topHead /@ {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][x, y, g[z][1, 2, 3]]}
```

> {f1, f2, f3}

Answer (score 9):

Another solution:

```
head[e_Symbol] := e
head[e_] := head@Head@e

head /@ {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]}
(* {f1,f2,f3} *)
```

Comment: consider also `head[h_[___]] := head[h]`

Answer (score 6):

I think [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) might be the purest way to handle this.

```
dh = Level[#, {-1}, # &, Heads -> True] &;

dh /@ {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]}
```

> ```
> {f1, f2, f3}
> ```

---

Other perhaps useful or entertaining methods:

```
lst = {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]};

Scan[Return, #, {-1}, Heads -> True] & /@ lst

Do @ MapAll[Break, #, Heads -> True] & /@ lst

# ~Extract~ Position[#, _, {-1}, 1][[1]] & /@ lst

FirstCase[#, _, , {-1}, Heads -> True] & /@ lst

Catch @ Operate[Throw@*#0, #] & /@ lst
```

Comment: You've got a lingering semicolon at the end of code line 2. Great answer!

Comment: @Roman Corrected / Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (with Mr.Wizard's suggestion of `x_?AtomQ` instead of `x_Symbol`):

```
f[x][y][z] /. x_?AtomQ :> Return[x, ReplaceAll]
(*  f  *)
```

Function:

```
rootHead = # /. x_?AtomQ :> Return[x, ReplaceAll] &;
```

MarcoB's examples:

```
lst = {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]};

rootHead /@ lst
(*  {f1, f2, f3}  *)
```

Comment: It's worth considering what happens with `1[x, y]` but +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, also `SparseArray[{0}][x][y][z]`, which I just discovered.  I guess it works only for nonatomic symbol heads.  Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: I suppose you could use `x_?AtomQ` instead?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, that's better. It still gives `1` or the whole `SparseArray[]` instead of their heads.

Comment: In many cases I think returning the verbatim head rather than its type is more useful.  Both `Head` and `h_[___]` etc. forms have been shared so there is choice, even though it hasn't been explicitly stated in this Q&A yet.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html)

```
rootHead = NestWhile[Head, #, # =!= Symbol &, 1, ∞, -1] &;

rootHead /@ {f1[a][x, y], f2[a, b, c], f3[a, 2][3]}
```

> {f1, f2, f3}